# Can't set Background for buttons iOS

Tags: ios, button, background, uibutton, ios-simulator

I made a simple app using the storyboard feature. I have made some `UIButton`s and I want to change the background of my `UIButton`s. In the storyboard the background successfully changes but in the actual iOS simulator my background does not change.

Comment: So you can see the image shown correctly in the storyboard, but when you load the Simulator there is not image for the button? Is it the same button? Is anything showing at all?

Comment: Is your app disable Autolayout ?

Comment: Sorry, where can I check it?

Comment: Background whether u mention background image or background colour?

Comment: No, there is only my button, without background

Comment: Kathiravan G, background image.

Comment: See here : http://i.stack.imgur.com/H2URN.png

Comment: iBhavin, so I compile my app with this setting and without but my problem doesn't solve...

Comment: Button for which u giving image whether for background or image.

Comment: Button have two properties image and background image . which one u setting.

Comment: Take a pic of your XIB with Attributes Inspector and load here.

Comment: iBhavin, you can see the settings here  http://imgur.com/k4gk3OO

Comment: And on iPhone I get the next: http://imgur.com/tj3fWFe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some suggestions for you:

1. If you set image programatically than check image name spelling, It should be match exactly with bundle image name(case sensitive).
2. You have to add two images in your bundle. e.g if image name is `nature.png` than you must have to add `nature.png` and `nature@2x.png`(`@2x` image must have double size than normal).
3. Although if you are using only one image for retina devices than check that you run your application in only retina devices, Sometime non-retina device won't show image.
4. If you set image as `UIButton` image with title than it is requited to set title and image insets, If  title text is big or image size is bigger.

Comment: I tried all of your tips but the problem don't solve(

Comment: Can you please share code in which you set button background image?

Comment: so I use storyboard. Must I make it with code too? You can see the settings here  http://i.imgur.com/k4gk3OO.png?1 and what on simulator here http://i.imgur.com/tj3fWFe.png?1  Sorry for my stupid questions...

Comment: We can clear see that image is not available at runtime. 

Follow these steps and check images are in bundle resource:

1) Select your project workspace from Xcode.
2) Select Build Phases tab
3) In that go to Copy Bundle Resources section.

Here check that your "Button_Continue.png" image is added
If not that tap on + button and add this image to bundle resource.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't directly understand you. So, may be you tell me this situation?   http://i.imgur.com/XisVQAl.png?1

Comment: Oops, I think I find solution. Thank you,  mehul patel

Comment: Every resources of our project like images, localization strings, html files also storyboard needs to copied when application compile and run. So when ever we add any kind of this file Xcode make an entry to "Build Phases >> Copy Bundle Resources". So compiler can copy items from these list to your application. So please check that your all images are list out in this section.

Comment: But if I've got a special folder for all images f.e. "Resourses" I must write the path like this: "Resourses\ image1.png" in storyboard?

Comment: No you just have to write image name only.