# UIImage imageNamed not setting image in iphone6

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview, iphone-6, iphone-6-plus

Hi am working on ios project using xcode 6.0.1,ios 8.While I am running my app in iphone6 simulator it is not showing my image.I have set my image using the following code,`[UIImage imageNamed:@"/Resources/btnbg.png"]`.What is the reason for this.it is perfectly working in my iphone4s.

Comment: Take a look on this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24908239/cant-set-background-for-buttons-ios/24909502#24909502

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your retina size image i.e. btnbg@2x.png.As may be the retina size image is not being loaded properly.As iphone 6 loads retina size images that is in the form of ImageName@2x.png.

Comment: This answer would be improved by expanding upon it a little. As it stands, it's a little too terse to be helpful to future readers.

Answer (score 1):

No need to write full path.

user only image name as below:

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"btnbg.png"]
```

It'll take full path automatically.

And also check @2x image of same image.